# Attractive iOS UIButtons at runtime

Tags: ios, uibutton, xamarin.ios, uiglassbutton

I have been using the Glass Button Generator from [here](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2010/08/uiglassbutton-generator-in-monotouch.html) to generate PNGs on iOS that look like UIGlassButtons yet don't use the UIGlassButton class (since it's private). These are then set as the image for custom UIButton instances. Works really nicely and looks great.

However I am now in a situation where I need to set the text on the buttons dynamically at runtime. The above approach won't work. I also need to dynamically set the size of the button in at least the vertical dimension.

UIButton as-is looks pretty ugly and flat. There must be some way of generating attractive buttons at runtime?

Non monotouch-specific solutions welcome, easy enough to translate.

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wanted to write my own GlassButton for a while, feel free to cut and paste it into your code, I made it part of my MonoTouch.Dialog library:

https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Utilities/GlassButton.cs

You use it like this:

```
 var glossy = new GlassButton (new RectangleF (0, 0, 120, 50)) {
     NormalColor = UIColor.Red,
     HighlightedColor = UIColor.Black,
     DisabledColor = UIColor.Black
 };
 glossy.Tapped += delegate {
      Console.WriteLine ("I have been tapped");
 }
 window.AddSubview (glossy);
```

Comment: It would be cool if we could map this button to the element or reflection api.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UIButton and add a UILabel as a subview.  This would be easier to do in straight C# than messing with Interface Builder.

Expose it's text property, and maybe others such as the font size, etc.

That should be all you need to get it working.

Comment: Already have infrastructure in place like this, but this doesn't solve the problem that UIButton by default is fugly.

Comment: I think using pre-created images is going to be the best option here.  UIKit is no WPF.  You are not going to easily generate pretty looking buttons with radial gradient brush, etc. in MonoTouch.  I would suggest creating a button look in Photoshop, etc. or get a graphic designer involved.

Comment: What about to add a Subview to the button to have uiImaveView for left part, right part and middle part. Than to adjust the mid images width according the label width. Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the button without nothing, and then, paint a UILabel with the text, the background of the UILabel with clearColor, put the UILabel just above the button, it will look like a part of the button.